# NetBeans Installation issues with JDK 10

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to run NetBeans 8.2.

So I installed the necessary requirement (JDK/JRE) but when I select the JDK folder it's says :

`An unknown error has occurred while validating the path.`

It's already peculiar that it didn't get recognized automatically but even if I select the folder manually it won't accept it.

[image]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JDK 8, not JDK 10.

The [installation instructions for NetBeans 8.2](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/install.html) say:

> The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 8 is required to install NetBeans IDE.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The specific failure is an irrelevant distraction since installing JDK 10 as the JDK for NetBeans 8.2 shouldn't even be attempted. NetBeans 8.2 does not support a JDK version > 8.